# Is there a better way to provide this function to a constructor?

Tags: c++, function, parameters

I have a class A which has a constructor with a function argument: i.e.

```
class A {
public:
  A(int (*f)(int);
};
```

I can create this class and have it use func() with, for example,

```
int func(int n);
A a(func);
```

I would like to invoke this class a number of times, but have it use internally func(n)+m instead of func(n).  I would prefer not to change class A.  I could create a new class to define the function I want

```
class B {
  int (*func)(int n);
  int m;
public:
  B(int (*ff)(int),int mm) : func(ff),m(mm) {}
  int myfunc(int n) { return(func(n)+m);
};
```

However, I don't think it is possible to convert a pointer to myfunc into a pointer with the required signature for A's constructor.

The way I have chosen is similar to the above, but with myfunc() and associated variables stored in the global space:

```
int m;
int (*func)(int);
int myfunc(int n) { return(func(n)+m); }
void setupmyfunc(int mm,int (*ff)(int)) { m=mm; func=ff; }
```

Then I can can create my A object with

```
setupmyfunc(m,func);
A a(myfunc);
```

This works, but seems inelegant to me.  Is there a better way?

Comment: [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)?

Comment: Regarding the `myfunc` usage you might also want to look into [`std::mem_fn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn)

Comment: Are you storing `f` in `A`, or calling it during construction? can `A` (or it's constructor) be a template?

Comment: It's not clear to me how you wish to use instances of `A` and `B` together.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish: without modifying A, create something (call it myptr) which can be used in {for int i=0; i<10; i++) A(myptr); and which will return func(n)+i instead of func(n).

Answer (score 2):

`std::function` can hold callable objects (functions, function objects, member function pointers (with object to bind to), etc.  It uses some type-erasure such that it can have this genericity, but comes at the cost of internal overhead to actually invoke it, often equivalent to a virtual function call.

Here's an example, where A takes a std::function, which allows you to pass in lambdas.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class A {
    std::function<int(int)> func_;
public:
    A(std::function<int(int)> func) : func_(func) {}

    int call(int x) {
        return func_(x);
    }
};

int foo(int x) {
    return x * 123; // whatever
}

int main() {
    // here's your wrapper function to do func(x)+m (m==9 in this case)
    A obj([](int x) { return foo(x) + 9; });

    int result = obj.call(123);
    std::cout << result << '\n';
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/94MfGM67K

---

Update:
Given the rejection of both answers so far, using std::function is out because it changes class `A`, and the obvious use of state-full lambdas for composition and capturing customization data is also out, you will need to get more creative and possibly ugly.  If you can't change A, then you can't change the signature of the function passed to a, so making the lambda take its data as another argument is also out.

Seems to me that leaves just one thing:  using state that is outside the function (i.e. global data or encoded in a template non-type template parameter) as a form of pseudo-capture that an otherwise stateless function can use.  I reject the global approach in general, though there's interesting aspects to it, and only present a template solution:

Now you write your free-standing functions and can compose them with a template:

```
#include <iostream>
using F = int(*)(int);

class A {
public:
  A(F f) : f_(f) { }
  int operator()(int x) { return f_(x); } // Added for demo
private:
  F f_;
};

template <F FuncF, F FuncG>
int compose(int n) {
    return FuncF(FuncG(n));
}

int func(int n) { return n * 1000; }
int add888(int n) { return n + 888; }
int add999(int n) { return n + 999; }

int main() {
    A a1(compose<add888, func>);
    A a2(compose<add999, func>);
    std::cout << a1(1) << " " << a2(1) << " " << a1(1);
}
// output: 1888 1999 1888
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8KsqbTcTd

This works as far back as c++11, and replacing the "using" with "typedef" it work in C++98.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution which does not require any change to A.

Comment: This is a good answer, but you appear to have only pasted a link to https://godbolt.org, and not to a specific compiler-explorer session on your last edit; you may want to update that.

Comment: @ghborrmann I updated to show another approach that works by using stateless free-standing functions and templates to compose others together.

Answer (score 2):

Stateless lambdas are implicitly convertible to function pointers so you can just use that without modifying your class `A` and without creating another class `B`. That is if I understood your question correctly.

```
class A {
public:
  A(int (*f)(int)) {};
};


int func(int n) { return n * 10; }

auto test()
{
    A a{[](int n) { return func(n) + 1; }};
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion works, but if I try to change your + 1 to + i, i.e, A a([i](int n) {return func(n)+i}); the signature doesn't match.

Comment: @ghborrmann `[i](int n) { .. ` is a steful lambda. Stateful lamdas cannot convert to function pointers. In this case you need `std::function` or make `A` templated by the function type.